# Passing data through render to template

Tags: python, django

I can pass the output from a `QuerySet` through a dictionary to my template (along with single variables), but I'm really struggling to understand how to best send data back to the template.

For example, I have news articles that I want to create a monthly link on. My `news` model has a field e.g. `news_monthyear = "2015/06"`.

I've created the following function in my `news/views`.

```
def build_news_archives():
    months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
    news_list = {}
    monthyear = News_Article.objects.order_by('news_monthyear').values('news_monthyear').distinct()
    for items in monthyear:
        year = items['news_monthyear'][:4]
        month = months[int(items['news_monthyear'][5:])-1]
        news_list[monthyear] = {'Year': year, 'Month' : month}
#    pdb.set_trace()
    return news_list
```

I've tried various techniques to build up my `news_list` variable ready for passing back to the template and just cannot work out how to structure it so I can easily access the data.

My main function that is used from `URLConf` contains the following:

```
def news(request, pID=0):
    rDict = {}
    if pID == 0:
        p = News_Article.objects.all()[:10]
    else:
        p = get_object_or_404(News_Article, id=pID)
    rDict['news'] = p
    announcement = get_announcement()
    if not announcement == None:
        rDict['announcement'] = announcement
    rDict['sitenav'] = clean_url(request.path, ['"', "'"])
    rDict['menu'] = Menu.objects.all().order_by('menu_position')
    rDict['newsarchive'] = build_news_archives()
#    pdb.set_trace()
    return render(request, 'en/public/news.html', rDict)
```

I've tried to access the data in my template like this, but I'm clearly missing something quite fundamental.

```html
  <ol class="list-unstyled">
  {% for archive in newsarchive %}
    <li>{{ archive.year }} + {{ archive.month }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`news_list[monthyear] = {'Year': year, 'Month' : month}`

The datastructure returned by `build_news_archive` is an object.  When iterating over an object in python (and django templates) the keys are iterated over by default

```
 <ol class="list-unstyled">
  {% for monthyear, archive in newsarchive.items %}
    <li>{{ archive.year }} + {{ archive.month }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ol>
```

you can call python `items` dict method in django template by accessing `your_dict.items` in a for loop
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Comment: Thanks, this suggestion worked.  Its blown my mind a bit to be honest. Not come across the .items at the end before.  Going to have to go and do some reading.  These different data structures and ways to access them keep catching me out.

Comment: In Python those are called dictionaries, not objects.

Comment: Hi @dm03514,   So, if i was to change the news_list so that it was  <br/>news_list[year] = {'month': month}  <br/>How can i loop this to nest it between year and then month so I can build up a list with year at the top, then each month of that year ? If that makes sense ?  <br/>

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you try to do this? The one thing I noticed is that you are referring to the dictionary keys 'Year' and 'Month' as 'year' and 'month' (noticed the difference in case of the first letter). The template is processed on the server side and hence should be case-sensitive. 
Other than that, dm03514's suggestion is should be incorporated as well.

Comment: Thanks @sid, that was another problem that I hadn't noticed. I'm usually quite good at that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this might help

```
return render(request, 'en/public/news.html', locals())

<ol class="list-unstyled">
  {% for archive in rDict.newsarchive %}
    <li>{{ archive.year }} + {{ archive.month }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ol>
```